# Is there a way to display a menu using the ol tag instead of the default ul tag?

Tags: template-tags

I'm trying to display a menu using `wp_nav_menu()`. The default markup that the function generates is a menu parented by a `<ul>` tag like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

My question is, is there a way to display a menu using the `<ol>` tag instead of the default `<ul>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `items_wrap` parameter to achieve this. For example like this:

```
'items_wrap' => '<ol id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ol>'
```

More information at [codex: `wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: This answer makes the top-most level `<ul>` into `<ol>`. However, submenus will still be rendered using `<ul>`

Comment: Then you have to extend and customize the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class. Take a look around there are plenty of answers concerning this around. @AbelMelquiadesCallejo